# How can I get a "done" button in softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

how can I have a "done" button in my softkeyboard (Samsung Galaxy 10.1, Android 3.1) when writing in an EditText?

Using

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/comment"
     android:layout_width="772dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

I get

[image]

If possible, I'd also like to remove this "attachment" button.

Anybody can help?

**EDIT**

I managed to get a "Done" button using

```
android:inputType="textImeMultiLine",
```

but the "return" button disappeared...

How can I have both? (I asked this new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016351/how-can-i-have-both-the-return-and-the-done-key-in-an-edittexts-softkeyboard)).

Comment: I think your screen is in portrait mode, so you are not able to see Done button, rotate screen to landscape mode it will visible on right side of EditText.

Comment: Yes my screen is in portrait mode. Is there any way to have both return and done button in portrait?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

add this to your EditText xml:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

or, to set it from code:

```
yourEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

for more, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionLabel)

Comment: are you using standard (android) keyboard?

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy 10.1, maybe they have customized softkeyboard?

Comment: i just tested on my phone with a standard keyboard, and it works fine

Comment: i dont think you can have `done` and `enter` key together, because they both replace each other

Comment: Ok, I'm going to ask my new question then. Thanks.

Comment: adding the following to the EditText xml, android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 5):

Using my Galaxy S2 phone

For the code below, each EditText will have a Return button that adds a new line:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
```

For the code below, each EditText will have a Next button that navigates to the next field and the last one will have Done button that will dismiss the keyboard:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

For the code below, no change, each EditText has a Return button:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

For the code below, all EditText will have a Done button and all will dismiss the keyboard.

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

For layouts use code below:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my Intel x86 Emulator at least, the "Done" key appears only if you specify the input type: "phone", "number", "text", "textPassword", ... with android:inputType.  If you don't specify any or you set "textMultiLine", "Done" does not appear.

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

and

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

seem useless, since they don't change anything either in the first case (where "Done" appears anyway) or in the in the second case (since "Done" keeps not appearing) !

Answer (score 1):

Add the next code to your EditText in xml

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:imeActionLabel="@string/done"
android:singleLine="true"
```

The `android:inputType="text"`  field is optional

Answer (score 0):

Use [TextView.setImeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions%28int%29) and pass it actionDone.