# How can I have both a return and a done keys in an EditText's softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

how can I have both a "done" (close the softkeyboard) and a "return" (line break) keys in my softkeyboard (Samsung Galaxy 10.1, Android 3.1, portrait mode) when writing in an EditText?

Using

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/comment"
     android:layout_width="772dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

I get

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That may depend on the application and what you mean by 'done'.
But, the KeyCode DPAD_UP and _DOWN ("arrow keys") will normally move the cursor to the next EditText.

Comment: I've got only one EditText. I'd like the 'return' key to add a line break to my text, and the 'done' key to close the softkeyboard.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.